# Bash alias for 'move a file to a directory, and then go to that directory'

Tags: macos, bash, shell, alias

So say I have a file in my home dir `~/`:

```
sample.txt
```

and I want to move it to `~/work/`

I would do  `mv sample.txt work/` and it would work.

But what if I want an alias that would mv the file, and then cd to the last arg? This means to move the file to a folder, and then automatically cd into that folder.

I have something like this (note that my `mv` is aliased for default overwrite protection, not sure if that's the issue):

```
alias mv='mv -i $@'
alias mvg='mv "$@"; cd !$;'
```

It doesn't work (seems like the mv isn't getting the args).

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using an alias, you could define a simple function:

```
mv_cd() { mv "$1" "$2" && cd "$2"; }
```

Usage: `mv_cd file dest`

That only works for one file. To allow multiple files, you could do something like this:

```
mv_cd() { 
    declare -a files
    while (($# > 1)); do 
        files+=("$1")
        shift
    done
    mv "${files[@]}" "$1" && cd "$1"
}
```

Usage: `mv_cd file1 file2 ... fileN dest`

This builds an array containing all of the file names that are passed to the function, then moves them and changes directory.

As mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649829/bash-alias-for-move-a-file-to-a-directory-and-then-go-to-that-directory/25650058?noredirect=1#comment40082241_25650058) (thanks @chepner), it's unnecessary to build an array inside the function. Instead, you can use array slicing to separate the last argument from the others:

```
mv_cd() { mv "${@:1:$#-1}" "${@: -1}" && cd "${@: -1}"; }
```

The arguments passed to the function are in the array `$@`. `${@:1:$#-1}` is a slice from the first element to the `$#-1`th element, where `$#` is the length of the array. Negative indices can be used to specify a range from the end of the array, so `${@: -1}` gets the last element of the array. There's no need to specify the end of the range, as it goes to the end of the array by default.

Comment: You can skip the array and just use `mv "${@:1:$#-1}" "${@: -1}" && cd "${@: -1}"` instead.

Comment: Good point, much more concise. I've edited my answer to include your suggestion. Thanks.